# Post a message to slack

Tags: c#, slack, slack-api

I want to post a message to slack on x channel I need to send the following x parameters how do I send the following parameters to a website

"channel": "XXXXX", "token": "token", "text": "text"

I am coding in c# mvc application.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendMessageAsync(string message, string channel = null, string userName = null)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        string url = "https://fake2604.slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?token=myToken&channel=" + channel + "&text=Hello World";

        var payLoad = new
        {
            text = message,
                   channel,
                   userName,
        };

        var serializedPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payLoad);

        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(serializedPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        return response;
    }
}
```

This is not working.It just adds an integration to the channel that I select in the OAuth page which again I got through Add to Slack button.

Comment: If you only want to post a message I would recommend to look into incoming webhooks. They do not require a token, only a URL.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken Could you tell me what is wrong with the above code? As it adds the integration but doesn't post the message

Comment: Have you tried using Postman to manually call the API or somehow manually test that everything else other than your code is working?

Comment: Also, you seem to be passing the payload both in the querystring *and* as JSON payload

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the problem is with your webhook url which you are adding some more stuff to that.this code definitely work:

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendMessageAsync(string message)
    {
        var payload = new
        {
            text = message,
            channel="x",
            userName="y",
        };
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var serializedPayload = serializer.ToJson(payload);
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("url",
            new StringContent(serializedPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        return response;
    }
```